# Understanding Closure: If $H$ is a group and $x^n \in H$, then $x \in H$

Tags: group-theory

I am reading Charles Pinter's A Book of Abstract Algebra and I just wanted to double check that I have a good understanding of closure.

Consider that a particular set is defined as $K=\{x: \text{for some n > 0,} \ \ x^n \in H \}$ where H is a group.

$x^n$ can be written in many equivalent ways: $(x^{n-1} \circ x)$, $(x^{n-2} \circ x^2)$, $(x^{n-3} \circ x^3)$, ect.

Using this, closure effectively guarantees that if $x^n$ is in a set, and this set is a group, I automatically know that $x^1$, $x^2$, $x^3$..., $x^{n-3}$, $x^{n-2}$,  and $x^{n-1}$ are also in the set, correct?

If this is the case, couldn't I **equivalently define $K$** as simply the group $H$?

Comment: Let $x = -1$ and $H = \{1\}$. Then $x^2 \in H$. Is $x \in H$?

Comment: It's related to one of the exercises. Specifically, Chapter 5 exercise C5.

Comment: @lhf that is correct...however, I didn't want to outright ask about the question in the book. I wanted to know if my initial approach in solving it was correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Consider $H=\{1\}$ and $G=\mathbb C^\times$. What is $K$?

The full statement of the problem is:

> Let $G$ be an abelian group and $H$ be a subgroup of $G$. Define $K=\{x \in G: x^n \in H, \text{for some } n > 0\}$. Prove that $K$ is a subgroup of $G$.

You just have to check that $K$ has the properties required of a subgroup. Be sure to note exactly where $G$ being abelian enters in the argument.

Comment: I am unsure of how G is involved in this. If H is simply {1}, then I do not see how it is a group...is the operation multiplication?

Comment: Yes $\space$ $\space$

Comment: @S.Cramer It satisfies all the axioms of a group. It’s called a trivial group.

Comment: I guess I do not understand the logic then. An identity element could be raised to any arbitrary power greater than 0 and still be equal to itself. Therefore, if H = {1}, I do not see why K would not also be {1}.

Comment: What is the fancy C notation? I am unfamiliar with it.

Comment: @S.Cramer Multiplicative group of complex numbers.

Comment: @S.Cramer In $\mathbb{C}^\times$, $K$ cannot be just $\{1\}$ because $-1 \in K$ because $(-1)^2 \in H$.

Comment: @S.Cramer In fact, all the [roots of unity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_of_unity) are in $K$.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. Cheers~

Comment: It seems to me that this arises when a group contains elements that are their own inverses. If the overarching group, with the exception of the identity element, does not have this quality, then K=H. Is that correct?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100119/discussion-between-s-cramer-and-user76284).

Answer (score 2):

No, closure means that if $x,y\in H$, then $x\circ y\in H$.
It does NOT mean that if $x\circ y\in H$, then $x,y\in H$.

In particular, your argument that $x^n\in H$ implies that $x^1\in H$ is wrong.